# How to open file based on current file path

Tags: key-bindings, buffers

Is there a way to retrieve the current filepath, modify it, and open the result?

To be more specific, let's say I'm editing `./some/file/awesome.controller.ts`

Then I'd like to automatically open `./some/file/awesome.html` (same file name, where `controller.ts` is replaced by `html`)

For now, the only thing I could come up with is something like

```
nnoremap <leader>ac :e @%<CR>
```

which is of course, completely useless since it does not modify the path string.

Thanks !

Comment: Related post: [Split: automatically load corresponding file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3853/778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I think what you are ultimately looking for is the [vim-projectionist plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) which lets you define how your files are named and allow you to easily switch between a controller and its view for example.

Otherwise you might want to read:

- [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29)
- [`:h filename-modifiers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)

For example when you are editing `./some/file/awesome.controller.ts`:

- `expand('%')` will return `rootDir/some/file/awesome.controller.ts`
- `expand('%:h')` will return `rootDir/some/file`

So you can play with that and maybe create a function which will take a user input and append it to the result of `expand('%:h')`.

Note that you might also want you get used to [`:h :find`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3afind)

Comment: Of course Tim Pope already did it... Many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for !