# Buffer list per window

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, list

How could I get something like a buffer/argument list or a filter for individual windows, with a chosen subset of the buffers?

So I could have a window just for header files in C (files ending in .h), which I can quickly cycle through, and navigate with a substring in a command like :b. But say there's both main.c and main.h, because it's looking at only *.h, using `:<dream-command-like-b> main` won't complain there's both main.c and main.h and will take me to main.h.

I see location lists are window-local but I don't think they're what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to implement such a feature yourself where you'd have dedicated functions to open and dispatch files into the right windows.

Comment: `arglist` **is** window-local, if you execute `:arglocal`.

Comment: it might be possible, but I am not aware of a plugin that provides this. So you might need to implement it yourself as a plugin.

Comment: Possibly related post: [Split: automatically load corresponding file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3853/778). Personally, I use [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the arglist is local to the current window.

The location list is a window-local quickfix list.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/vim-ctrlspace/vim-ctrlspace . It attaches  buffers to a tab. `Ctrl-space + w` to navigate buffers in the tab(by default).

I think that is the default but I might have changed the plugin locally.

Comment: I guess that you want a buffer list per tab since it is more reasonable. I don't know about buffer list per window.